# Android app keeps crashing after displaying my splashscreen

Tags: java, android, xml

The app keeps crashing i have been trying trying many times searching online but i still cant get it
Do anyone know what is the cause of the app keep crashing? Im new to this got school assignment.
Can i copy a code from another file which have a different domain and paste it to other file with different domain?
How can i copy a file from a different domain and paste to another file

Logcat

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: sp.com, PID: 31720
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{sp.com/sp.com.DetailsFragment}: java.lang.ClassCastException: sp.com.DetailsFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: sp.com.DetailsFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1174)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2669)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Android Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.P2120287Assignment">
        <activity
            android:name=".DetailsFragment"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/SplashScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: `java.lang.ClassCastException: sp.com.DetailsFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Activity` The `<activity>` declaration in the manifest must contain Activities, not Fragments.

Answer (score 2):

In the manifest file you are referencing a `Fragment` inside an `activity` tag:

```
<activity
    android:name=".DetailsFragment"
    android:exported="false">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.lib_name"
        android:value="" />
</activity>
```

This is not possible. You need to reference an `Activity` here.

Comment: Thankyou Now i got a different error